# Azure: export azure app service certificate locally

Tags: azure, ssl, azure-web-app-service, azure-keyvault

Referring to the question asked here, [Azure: manually add app service certificate to key vault](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53202773/azure-manually-add-app-service-certificate-to-key-vault)

Also quoting to answer given,

" App Service Certificate stores the private certificate into a user-provided Key Vault secret. When App Service Certificate is deployed into a web app, a Web Apps resource provider deploys it from the Key Vault secret that's associated with App Service Certificate.

So, when you add app service certificate to azure keyvault, you could not see anything in Certificate option. "

As I cannot see certificates in the key vault but the certificate is stored in user provided secret, but how to export it then?

Comment: you simply can't.... add you cert to key vault then link it to your app service. this way it will work

Comment: Well, I found that certificate in secrets, I exported secrets as .pfx format using poweshell.